# Converts a double space into single one anywhere in a String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to complete a function that converts
double space in a String into a single space in Haskell.

```
normaliseSpace:: String -> String
normaliseSpace (x:y:xs)= if x==' ' && y==' ' then y:xs
else xs
```

The problem with my code  is that only converts double spaces in the beginning of a String. I suppose it has something to do with pattern matching, but as I am completely new to Haskell I really don't have an idea how to do it. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Try using recursion for the other case.

Comment: What should triple-spaces do? You might consider `normaliseSpace = unwords . words` if you're okay with collapsing arbitrarily long sequences of whitespace (but beware: including newlines) to a single space.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this happens is because `y:xs` and `xs` will not *recurse* on te rest of the string. You thus want to perform the function on the rest of the string.

You thus should call `normaliseSpace` on `xs` as tail. For example:

```
normaliseSpace:: String -> String
normaliseSpace "" = ""
normaliseSpace (' ' : ' ' : xs) = ' ' : normaliseSpace xs
normalissSpace (x:xs) = x : normaliseSpace xs
```

Note that you need to add a pattern for the empty string (list) as well. Since otherwise eventually the recursion will reach the end of the list, and thus raise an error because there is no clause that can "fire".

If you want to reduce a sequence of spaces (two or *more* to one), then we even need to pass `' ' : xs` through the `normalizeSpace`, like [@leftroundabout says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710107/converts-a-double-space-into-single-one-anywhere-in-a-string-in-haskell/58710168?noredirect=1#comment103714167_58710168):

```
normaliseSpace:: String -> String
normaliseSpace "" = ""
normaliseSpace (' ' : ' ' : xs) = normaliseSpace (' ':xs)
normalissSpace (x:xs) = x : normaliseSpace xs
```

We can use an as-pattern here, like [@JosephSible suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710107/converts-a-double-space-into-single-one-anywhere-in-a-string-in-haskell/58710168?noredirect=1#comment103833411_58710168):

```
normaliseSpace:: String -> String
normaliseSpace "" = ""
normaliseSpace (' ' : xs@(' ' : _)) = normaliseSpace xs
normalissSpace (x:xs) = x : normaliseSpace xs
```

Comment: Actually, it would likely be better to recurse `normaliseSpace $ ' ':xs`, so multiple-spaces are also reduced to one. (But this is not clear from the OP.)

Comment: That works great. Thank you very much! I tried using recursion before, but I have missed on of the base cases most likely.

Comment: Why rebuild `' ':xs` instead of using an at-pattern?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can simply do like

```
*Main> let normSpaces = unwords . words
*Main> normSpaces "hello     world"
"hello world"
```