# Haskell how to remove excessive spaces in a String

Tags: haskell

Trying to create a function that removes all double/triple etc spaces in a
string (and merges them into one single space)

So far I have been able to get double spaces to remove, but not sure how to go about triple and more.

i.e `"a b  c   d    e"` -> `"a b c d e"`

```
formatSpace :: String -> String
formatSpace [] = []
formatSpace (' ':' ':xs) = ' ': formatSpace xs
formatSpace (x:xs)   = x: formatSpace xs
```

Thought about trying to turn all spaces into say '-' and then turn all those into a single space. 
Been able to move and leading and trailing whitespace, but can't do this one

Comment: See comments to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58710168/745903

Comment: @leftaroundabout thank you! your comment on the other post was perfect!

Comment: There is a trivial solution if you can use the pre-defined `words` and `unwords` functions.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
formatSpace :: String -> String
formatSpace = foldr go ""
  where
    go x acc = x:if x == ' ' then dropWhile (' ' ==) acc else acc
```

This is maximally lazy and doesn't create any unnecessary intermediate data structures.